# SwiftUI: How to properly present AVPlayerViewController modally?

Tags: swiftui, presentmodalviewcontroller, avplayerviewcontroller, avkit

### Proper UIKit Approach:

According to Apple's [WWDC 2019 talk on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/503/), `AVPlayerViewController` should be presented modally to take advantage of all the latest full-screen features of the API. This is the recommended sample code to be called from your presenting UIKit view controller:

```
// Create the player
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)

// Create the player view controller and associate the player
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.player = player

// Present the player view controller modally
present(playerViewController, animated: true)
```

This works as expected and launches the video in beautiful full-screen.

### Achieve the Same Effect with SwiftUI?:

In order to use the `AVPlayerViewController` from SwiftUI, I created the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` implementation:

```
struct AVPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var videoURL: URL

    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.player?.play()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        return AVPlayerViewController()
    }
}
```

> I cannot seem to figure out how to present this directly from SwiftUI
>   in the same way as the `AVPlayerViewController` is presented directly
>   from UIKit. My goal is simply to get all of the default, full-screen benefits.

So far, the following has not worked:

- If I use a `.sheet` modifier and present it from within the sheet, then the player is embedded in a sheet and not presented full-screen.
- I have also tried to create a custom, empty view controller in UIKit that simply presents my `AVPlayerViewController` modally from the `viewDidAppear` method. This gets the player to take on the full screen, but it also shows an empty view controller prior to display the video, which I do not want the user to see.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can overlay the AVPlayerView() on the current View

Comment: Do you want real full-screen covering everything or only covering a certain view, so excluding tab bars?

Answer (score 14):

Just a thought if you like to fullscreen similar like UIKit, did you try the following code from ContentView.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let toPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(EmptyView()))
    @State private var vURL = URL(string: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4")
    var body: some View {
        AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$vURL).transition(.move(edge: .bottom)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


struct AVPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @Binding var videoURL: URL?

    private var player: AVPlayer {
        return AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
        playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        playerController.player = player
        playerController.player?.play()
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        return AVPlayerViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when presented as a `.sheet`.  The sheet will be displayed as a SwiftUI modal, with the small gap at the top. If you rotate the device or tap the expand to fullscreen button at the top-left, the player enters fullscreen mode.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `toPresent = UIHostingController`? Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm just getting started in Swift development.

Answer (score 11):

The solution explained by Razib-Mollick was a good start for me, but it was missing the use of the SwiftUI `.sheet()` method. I have added this by adding the following to `ContentView`:

```swift
    @State private var showVideoPlayer = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showVideoPlayer = true }) {
            Text("Start video")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showVideoPlayer) {
            AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$vURL)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
```

But the problem is then, that the AVPlayer is instantiated again and again when SwiftUI re-renders the UI.
Therefore the state of the AVPlayer has to move to a `class` object stored in the environment, so we can get hold of it from the `View struct`. So my latest solution looks now as follows. I hope it helps somebody else.

```swift
class PlayerState: ObservableObject {

    public var currentPlayer: AVPlayer?
    private var videoUrl : URL?

    public func player(for url: URL) -> AVPlayer {
        if let player = currentPlayer, url == videoUrl {
            return player
        }
        currentPlayer = AVPlayer(url: url)
        videoUrl = url
        return currentPlayer!
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var playerState : PlayerState
    @State private var vURL = URL(string: "https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/media/bbb-360p.mp4")

    @State private var showVideoPlayer = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showVideoPlayer = true }) {
            Text("Start video")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showVideoPlayer, onDismiss: { self.playerState.currentPlayer?.pause() }) {
            AVPlayerView(videoURL: self.$vURL)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .environmentObject(self.playerState)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .environmentObject(PlayerState())
    }
}


struct AVPlayerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    @EnvironmentObject var playerState : PlayerState
    @Binding var videoURL: URL?

    func updateUIViewController(_ playerController: AVPlayerViewController, context: Context) {
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        playerController.player = playerState.player(for: videoURL!)
        playerController.player?.play()
        return playerController
    }
}
```

Something to be aware of (a bug?): whenever a modal sheet is shown using `.sheet()` the environment objects are not automatically passed to the subviews. They have to be added using `environmentObject()`.
Here is a link to read more about this problem: https://oleb.net/2020/sheet-environment/

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode 12 · iOS 14**

→ Use `.fullScreenCover` instead of `.sheet` and you’re good to go.

See also: [How to present a full screen modal view using fullScreenCover](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-present-a-full-screen-modal-view-using-fullscreencover)

Comment: The problem with using fullScreenCover is that you lose the original functionality from UIKit of the "swipe to dismiss" the controller. You can now only press the "x" dismiss button provided by the controller.